# Stacked bars CharJs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola amigos, estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente y es que quiero lograr algo como esa imagen pero con CharJS, lo mas parecido que encontré en el CharJS son los Stacked bars pero  lo que hace es que monta datos encima de otros.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:
Azul: Venta total
Verde: Neto (Venta-Gastos)
Rojo: No se ve pero si hubiese seria si el resultado entre venta-gastos arroja un numero negativo.

Si lo hago con CharJS me monta el verde encima del azul y no es funcional, lo que quiero es que me muestre cada barra desde el 0 hacia arriba pero juntas horizontalmente hablando, que no se separen unas de otras, como se ve en esta imagen.

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código.

Comment: ¿Tu quieres grupos de 3 columnas una al lado de la otra que partan del cero o una sola columna con 3 grupos en ella, como en tu imagen?

Comment: Como en la imagen, 3 columnas en la misma posicion X que partan desde cero, la que tenga mayor valor quedara visible por detras de la que tenga menor valor.

Answer (score 0):

[**Chart.js**](https://www.chartjs.org/) nos permite montar diferentes barras en una con la propiedad de `Stacked Bar`.

Pero como tu comentas, tiene una pega. No es capaz de atribuir un color dependiendo de el origen de un valor dentro de diferentes matrices.

Tenemos por ejemplo los siguientes `arrays` (*matrices*)

```
number1 = [10, 19, 3, 7, 4, 3];
number2 = [13, 5, 5, 6, 6, 20];
number3 = [20, 15, 2, 2, 1, 1];
```

Cada columna representa una barra con sus tres divisiones.

Necesitamos ordenarlos de tal forma que en la parte superior se ecuestre el numero mas alto y por debajo los menores.

```js
number1 = [10, 19, 3, 7, 4, 3];
number2 = [13, 5, 5, 6, 6, 20];
number3 = [20, 15, 2, 2, 1, 1];

var max = [];
var min = [];
var middle = [];

for(i = 0; i < number1.length; i++){
   max[i] = Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   min[i] = Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   middle[i] = number1[i]+number2[i]+number3[i] - Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]) -Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
}

console.log("Max")
console.log(max)
console.log("Medio")
console.log(middle)
console.log("Min")
console.log(min)
```

Como se observa se crearon **3** nuevas arrays las cuales contiene:

1. **Máximo valor.**
2. **Mínimo valor.**
3. **El valor entre el Máximo y el Mínimo.**

De esta forma ya podemos ordenarlos.

El problema es asignar un color especifico a cada valor y como saber que color corresponde a dicho valor.

Para ello utilizaremos una comprobación quizás un poco tosca de la mano de los [**`if`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/if...else)

```
if (number1[i] == max[i]) {
    console.log("Coincidencia max")
    backgroundcolorFirst.push('#87CEFA73');
    backgroundborderFisrt.push('#87CEFAE6')
    labelfirst.push('Ventas Totales')
}
```

Lo que buscamos aquí es comprobar si en el la misma fila que el arreglo `number1` y `max` se encuentra un numero igual.

De ser así almacenara en **3** nuevas arrays informacion como el **colore de fondo**, **bordeado**  y **nombres** (label) para poder personalizar nuestra barra acorde a un determinado valor de origen.

```js
number1 = [10, 19, 3, 7, 4, 3];
number2 = [13, 5, 5, 6, 6, 20];
number3 = [20, 15, 2, 2, 1, 1];

var max = [];
var min = [];
var middle = [];

var backgroundcolorFirst = [];
var backgroundborderFisrt = [];
var labelfirst = [];

for(i = 0; i < number1.length; i++){
   max[i] = Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   min[i] = Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   middle[i] = number1[i]+number2[i]+number3[i] - Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]) -Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);

   // Comprobacion number1
   if (number1[i] == max[i]) {
      console.log("Coincidencia max")
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelfirst.push('Ventas Totales')
   }

   if (number1[i] == min[i]) {
      console.log("Coincidencia min")
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelfirst.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }

   if (number1[i] == middle[i]) {
      console.log("Coincidencia middle")
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#008f39E6')
      labelfirst.push('Neto')
   }
}
```

Esto se repetiría **2** veces mas para las demás diviciones `middle` y `min`.

Como resultado obtendremos lo siguiente:

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeDraw: function(c) {
      var legends = c.legend.legendItems;
      legends.forEach(function(e) {
         e.fillStyle = '#0077CC';
         e.strokeStyle ='#0077CCBF'
      });
   }
});

number1 = [10, 19, 3, 7, 4, 3];
number2 = [13, 5, 5, 6, 6, 20];
number3 = [20, 15, 2, 2, 1, 1];

var max = [];
var min = [];
var middle = [];

var backgroundcolorFirst = [];
var backgroundcolorSecond = [];
var backgroundcolorThird = [];

var backgroundborderFisrt = [];
var backgroundborderSecond = [];
var backgroundborderThird = [];

var labelfirst = [];
var labelSecond = [];
var labelThird = [];

var forvalue = Math.max(number1.length, number2.length, number3.length)

for(i = 0; i < forvalue; i++){
   number1[i] = number1[i] ? number1[i] : 0;
   number2[i] = number2[i] ? number2[i] : 0;
   number3[i] = number3[i] ? number3[i] : 0;

   max[i] = Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   min[i] = Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   middle[i] = number1[i]+number2[i]+number3[i] - Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]) - Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);

   // Comprobacion number1
   if (number1[i] == max[i]) {
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelfirst.push('Ventas Totales')
   }

   if (number1[i] == min[i]) {
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelfirst.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }

   if (number1[i] == middle[i]) {
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#008f39E6')
      labelfirst.push('Neto')
   }
   // Comprobacion number2
   if (number2[i] == max[i]) {
      backgroundcolorSecond.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderSecond.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelSecond.push('Ventas Totales')
   }
   
   if (number2[i] == min[i]) {
      backgroundcolorSecond.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderSecond.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelSecond.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }
   
   if (number2[i] == middle[i]) {
      backgroundcolorSecond.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderSecond.push('#008f39E6')
      labelSecond.push('Neto')
   }
   // Comprobacion number3
   if (number3[i] == max[i]) {
      backgroundcolorThird.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderThird.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelThird.push('Ventas Totales')
   }
         
   if (number3[i] == min[i]) {
      backgroundcolorThird.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderThird.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelThird.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }
         
   if (number3[i] == middle[i]) {
      backgroundcolorThird.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderThird.push('#008f39E6')
      labelThird.push('Neto')
   }
 }
 
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Linea 3 (Min)',
        labels: labelThird,
        data: min,
        backgroundColor: backgroundcolorThird,
        borderColor: backgroundborderThird,
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
        label: 'Linea 2 (Medio)',
        labels: labelSecond,
        data: middle,
        backgroundColor: backgroundcolorSecond,
        borderColor: backgroundborderSecond,
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
         label: 'Linea 1 (Max)',
         labels: labelfirst,
         data: max,
         backgroundColor: backgroundcolorFirst,
         borderColor: backgroundborderFisrt,
         borderWidth: 2
       }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var index = tooltipItem.index;
          return dataset.labels[index] + ": " + dataset.data[index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

> que no se separen unas de otras, como se ve en esta imagen.

Si lo que quieres es que permanezcan uno al lado del otro sin separaciones entre ellos. 
Puedes aplicar esto desde una configuración inicial, antes que se cargue el gráfico Chartjs (v2.9.3).

```
Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.categoryPercentage = 1.11;
```

Si usas una versión mas antigua puede aplicarlo en el apartado `xAxes`.

```
categoryPercentage: 1.0,
barPercentage: 1.0,
```

```js
Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.categoryPercentage = 1.10;
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeDraw: function(c) {
      var legends = c.legend.legendItems;
      legends.forEach(function(e) {
         e.fillStyle = '#0077CC';
         e.strokeStyle ='#0077CCBF'
      });
   }
});

number1 = [10, 19, 3, 7, 4, 3];
number2 = [13, 5, 5, 6, 6, 20];
number3 = [20, 15, 2, 2, 1, 1];

var max = [];
var min = [];
var middle = [];

var backgroundcolorFirst = [];
var backgroundcolorSecond = [];
var backgroundcolorThird = [];

var backgroundborderFisrt = [];
var backgroundborderSecond = [];
var backgroundborderThird = [];

var labelfirst = [];
var labelSecond = [];
var labelThird = [];

var forvalue = Math.max(number1.length, number2.length, number3.length)

for(i = 0; i < forvalue; i++){
   number1[i] = number1[i] ? number1[i] : 0;
   number2[i] = number2[i] ? number2[i] : 0;
   number3[i] = number3[i] ? number3[i] : 0;

   max[i] = Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   min[i] = Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);
   middle[i] = number1[i]+number2[i]+number3[i] - Math.min(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]) - Math.max(number1[i], number2[i], number3[i]);

   // Comprobacion number1
   if (number1[i] == max[i]) {
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelfirst.push('Ventas Totales')
   }

   if (number1[i] == min[i]) {
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelfirst.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }

   if (number1[i] == middle[i]) {
      backgroundcolorFirst.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderFisrt.push('#008f39E6')
      labelfirst.push('Neto')
   }
   // Comprobacion number2
   if (number2[i] == max[i]) {
      backgroundcolorSecond.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderSecond.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelSecond.push('Ventas Totales')
   }
   
   if (number2[i] == min[i]) {
      backgroundcolorSecond.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderSecond.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelSecond.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }
   
   if (number2[i] == middle[i]) {
      backgroundcolorSecond.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderSecond.push('#008f39E6')
      labelSecond.push('Neto')
   }
   // Comprobacion number3
   if (number3[i] == max[i]) {
      backgroundcolorThird.push('#87CEFA73');
      backgroundborderThird.push('#87CEFAE6')
      labelThird.push('Ventas Totales')
   }
         
   if (number3[i] == min[i]) {
      backgroundcolorThird.push('#ff000073');
      backgroundborderThird.push('#ff0000E6')
      labelThird.push('Venta-Gastos')
   }
         
   if (number3[i] == middle[i]) {
      backgroundcolorThird.push('#008f3973');
      backgroundborderThird.push('#008f39E6')
      labelThird.push('Neto')
   }
 }
 

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Linea 3 (Min)',
        labels: labelThird,
        data: min,
        backgroundColor: backgroundcolorThird,
        borderColor: backgroundborderThird,
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
        label: 'Linea 2 (Medio)',
        labels: labelSecond,
        data: middle,
        backgroundColor: backgroundcolorSecond,
        borderColor: backgroundborderSecond,
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
         label: 'Linea 1 (Max)',
         labels: labelfirst,
         data: max,
         backgroundColor: backgroundcolorFirst,
         borderColor: backgroundborderFisrt,
         borderWidth: 2
       }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var index = tooltipItem.index;
          return dataset.labels[index] + ": " + dataset.data[index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```